# Selenium, Robot framework using this we have to click the button as described below

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How to click this button using robot framework and selenium2library?

```
<button type="button" tabindex="0">Explore the Show</button>
```

I have tried with xpath, that doesn't work out....it changes in every run!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!! please read [mcve] and add some missing details in your post accordingly like - show you code trials, errors .. in order to get maximum response

Answer (score 0):

If the text stays the same all the time, you could try this:

`//button[text()='Explore the Show']`

If you could provide the page source or additional HTML, that would be helpful. If you are receiving an error message, posting it here would help too.